# Jquery Slide Menu Multi Level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, panels

I have been adapting the below fiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5owq24cj/1/
```

If you click -

```
Target 1 > Target 4? >
```

All the menus open correctly.

But if I then click `"Target 2"` it only resets the "middle" panel?

Is there a way to always reset the "middle" and "right" panels when clicking a link in the "left" panel?

NOTE: Credit goes to `http://jsfiddle.net/user/sg3s/fiddles/` for the original fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Would this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5owq24cj/5/) work? I modified the `$other` to include the rightmost active panel (if any):

`$other = $target.siblings('.active').add('#right2 .active'),`

this would reset it when another link is clicked in the left panel.